# Squares of an $8\times8$ grid are coloured black or white. How many colourings of an $8\times8$ grid are there?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The squares of an $8\times8$ grid are coloured black or white. A colouring is called **balanced** if each $2\times2$ **subgrid contains *exactly* two squares of each colour** 
(i.e. Any $2\times2$ subgrid can't have 3 of white and 1 of black or full colour.)

---

Counting the **rotations and reflections** of a pattern as **different**, how many **balanced** colourings of the $8\times8$ grid are there?

Any help would very much be appreciated. This question is doing my head in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can produce $2^8$ balanced colorings by choosing the first row arbitrarily, then making each column alternate black and white. You can also produce $2^8$ balanced colorings by choosing the first column arbitrarily, then making each row alternate black and white. That would make $2^8 + 2^8$ colorings, except I counted the two chessboard colorings twice, so that makes $2^8 + 2^8 - 2 = 510$ colorings total.

**Claim**: there are no other colorings.

Proof: Assume there *is* another coloring that hasn't been listed yet. It's not a chessboard coloring, so there must be two adjacent squares of the same color.

Suppose wlog. they're adjacent horizontally. Then what can we say about the two columns these squares are in? The two squares above these squares have the opposite color, and the two squares above *those* have the opposite color again, and so on. So these two columns are identical, alternating black and white.

What about the columns next to those alternating colums? They must also alternate black and white, since if they weren't at some point, that point would be part of an unbalanced 2x2 square. The same goes for the next columns, and by induction you see that each column is alternating black and white.

But wait, now this coloring we chose is one of the colorings listed in the first paragraph. Contradiction! So the assumption is false and the claim is true.

Comment: A proof would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: I've provided a proof.

Comment: @user525966 In your example, the columns don't alternate, but now the rows alternate. I didn't miss that.

Comment: @Magma I mostly follow you, but I'm confused about the second-to-last paragraph. Let's say the particular board has a top row BBWWBBWW, and the colors flip back and forth on the rows beneath. I now focus on the BB in the fifth and sixth positions. Applying your reasoning in the second-to-last paragraph, the colors in that row would be BWBWBBWB, which isn't the case. I'm thinking I mis-read what you meant. Would you be willing to clarify?

Comment: @John Each column is individually alternating black and white. The next column is not uniquely determined though, it can either be an identical copy of the previous column, or an inverted copy.

Comment: @Magma thanks and +1